# initialize ms access form fields

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, initialization, refresh

Is there a generic VBA code for initializing all fields on an MS Access form? I am very weak in the VBA coding department but i would like to have the form initialized in the following 2 conditions:

1) When someone double clicks the form to open it.
2) After someone clicks the "save" button to save the newly created record.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**edit**

i have tried using the `me.refresh` code in the "on click" event and it does not seem to initialize all fields. The only code in the form is the following:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)


   Dim ctl As Control

   On Error GoTo Err_BeforeUpdate


   If Me.Dirty Then

      If MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
              "Save Record") = vbNo Then
         Me.Undo
      End If
   End If

Exit_BeforeUpdate:
   Exit Sub

Err_BeforeUpdate:
   MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
   Resume Exit_BeforeUpdate
End Sub
```

Comment: let me rephrase for the person who downgraded my question. I have used the `me.refresh` code on the "on click" event and it does not seem to initialize all fields.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but we need more information. What is happening on this form that it needs to be "initialized?"

Comment: @OverMind a user essentially enters in records for their time allocation for their days worked. There are several combo boxes, date fields and 1 free form text field.

Comment: Are these fields linked to a table?

Comment: So when the user hits the button to save their newly entered time record, why does the form need to be "initialized" again?? Is it loading a new empty time record for the current employee? Is it loading some time record for the "next" employee?

Comment: Try this after the data is inserted.. `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`

Comment: @OverMind yes the fields are all linked to a table that stores all the entries.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff the issue is that they have to hit the "add record" button every time because simply hitting the "save record" button does not clear all fields for the same user to enter in another set of records.

Comment: @OverMind can you explain what you mean when you say "after the data is inserted"?

Comment: On the event handler for the button click; paste that code in it. Let me know what happens.

Comment: He means after the last End If. In other words, after you have saved the data (or chosen not to save it), load a new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only differences between #'s 1 and 2 are the event handlers.

## 1

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

## 2

```
Private Sub SomeButton_Click()
'Your code to save the record the user entered
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

Both of these Subs should go to the next (new) record.

On `Me.Refresh` :

Me.Refresh only updates the records in the current form, but will not show new or deleted records.

Comment: isntead of using `Private Sub SomeButton_Click()` i used the `After Update` event and it works perfect

Comment: @JT2013 great. Yes - cater this code to your needs. It seems as though you have the hang of it.